# pushstate only working once

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, pushstate

I have 3 links, 2 with a pushstate data 1 without. Users + Tags link has data, topics doesnt. If i click users then topics then back or tags then topics then back it works perfect. if I click users then tags then click back it will only load the last pushstate (tags). if i click tags then users then back it just reuses the users pushstate. if i go tags -> users -> topics, back will goto users, back again will also be users ??

```
$('#changetousers').click(function () {
   $('#loadingAjaxs').show(); $('#flubestext').hide();
   $('#contentwrap').load('@Url.Action("FollowingUsersDetail", "Following", new {@ajax = "yes"})', function () { $('#loadingAjaxs').hide(); $('#flubestext').show(); window.history.pushState({ "page": "followingusers" }, 'title1', '/users/'); window.onpopstate = function (e) { document.getElementById('changetousers').click(); };
   })
});

$('#changetotags').click(function () {
   $('#loadingAjaxs').show(); $('#flubestext').hide();
   $('#contentwrap').load('@Url.Action("FollowingTagsDetail", "Following", new {@ajax = "yes"})', function () { $('#loadingAjaxs').hide(); $('#flubestext').show(); window.history.pushState({ "page": "followingtags" }, 'title2', '/tags/'); window.onpopstate = function (e) { document.getElementById('changetotags').click(); }; })
});

$('#changetofavorites').click(function () {
    $('#loadingAjaxs').show(); $('#flubestext').hide();
    $('#contentwrap').load('@Url.Action("FollowingTopicsDetail", "Following", new {@ajax = "yes"})', function () { $('#loadingAjaxs').hide(); $('#flubestext').show(); window.history.pushState(null, 'title', '/favorites/'); })
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you calling the `pushState` even user clicks to back, this is why you cannot go to previous state. This should work:

```
function loadUserDetails() {
    $('#loadingAjaxs').show();
    $('#flubestext').hide();
    $('#contentwrap').load(
        '@Url.Action("FollowingUsersDetail", "Following", new {@ajax = "yes"})', 
        function () { 
            $('#loadingAjaxs').hide(); 
            $('#flubestext').show();
        });
}
$('#changetousers').click(function () {
    loadUserDetails();
    window.history.pushState({ "page": "followingusers" }, 'title1', '/users/');
    window.onpopstate = function (e) { loadUserDetails(); };
});
```